# How can I change the keyboard shortcut key to open Quicksilver?

Tags: quicksilver, filesystem

Fyi.. I searched Apple.SE and didn't found an answer, so I am posting here.

Currently I open Quicksilver by Ctrl + Shift + spacebar. And my Spotlight preference is Cmd + spacebar.

Most of the time I use Quicksilver, I would like to change this. I know how to change this for spotlight, but not sure for QS.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Now I am able to see the preferences screen with some menu's and here is the screenshot. Am I running very old build/ version ?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information about your system? Mac OS X version, Quicksilver version, where you downloaded it?

Comment: OS X 10.6.5, Quicksilver β54 (3815) [from 'About Quicksilver' dialog box]. I am not sure where I downloaded it, but I did it nearly 11 months back.

Comment: Can you post what you see in console related to Quicksilver? (`Applications -> Utilities -> Console.app`)

Comment: @Nivas - here it is... 12/12/10 8:35:27 PM Quicksilver[227] Prevented load of unidentified action from bundle Core Support.qsplugin because the action's featureLevel (set from its Info.plist) is higher than NSApp's current featureLevel. This is not neccessarily an error. Sometimes this mechanism is used to prevent unstable actions from loading.

Comment: Looks like you are running a old build (as you have guessed). Try to remove all app related files (including preferences) and reinstall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open QuickSilver, and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to access Preferences.

Go to the `Command` tab and change `HotKey Actionvation` to the shortcut you want to use.

If the command you want to set is the same as the Spotlight one, you'll first have to change the Spotlight shortcut.

[image: quicksilver preferences]

Comment: Looks good, but the main issue is, I am unable to see anything on preferences window after I press Cmd + , it's just a blank screen. So is my choice is to re-install QS or any troubleshoot options ?

Comment: I just updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: I accepted this as answer because you put the info straight for what i asked. Also @calavera helped me to debug my issue, so I upvoted him.

Answer (score 2):

I would try upgrading your version.  Mine is currently at ß58 (3841).

If after upgrading you're still having issues, I would remove the app and all related files/folders and reinstall.

Comment: I removed my current Quicksilver app (moved to trash) and downloaded new version and copied that to Applications --> Utilities. And when I try to launch the app, it's not opened successfully and may be some errors. Then I opened Console.app and searched for Quicksilver, then found this error --> Quicksilver[227] Prevented load of unidentified action from bundle Core Support.qsplugin because the action's featureLevel (set from its Info.plist) is higher than NSApp's current featureLevel. This is not neccessarily an error. Sometimes this mechanism is used to prevent unstable actions from loading.

Comment: thanks. I removed QS settings and cache with help of AppCleaner and reinstalled it. Now I am able to use it.